# Query "Bulk Data Load Jobs" IDs

Tags: bulk-api, bulk

Is there a way to use WorkBench/Apex/Rest-Explorer to query all "Bulk Data Load Jobs" IDs for last X days?

Use Case - We want to set up some logs and monitoring on different users consuming our org bulk API limits. We are open to writing an application internal/external to SF. I just need to know what SF API could provide all these bulk job Ids. Once we have the Ids, I believe getting the details is available through APIs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the below article. It seems something I could use.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/get_all_jobs.htm